# How to make FileUtils appends instead of overwriting text file

Tags: java, file, apache-commons-io

I am using the following to write `StringBuilder` into an existing text file.

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, sb.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The problem is that it overwrites the file where I just want to **append** `sb.toString()` to the existing content of `file`. How to workaround this issue?

Comment: Take a look at [the API docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), one line down from `writeStringToFile(File file, String data)` is `writeStringToFile(File file, String data, boolean append)`

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1625263/5758826

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been implemented in 2.1 version of Apache IO. To append string to the file just pass true as an additional parameter in functions:

example:

```
 FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, stringBuilder.toString(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to [`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), there's an overloaded variant that takes a `boolean` append parameter:

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, sb.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, true);
// Here -----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the method with the `append` boolean:

[`writeStringToFile(File file, String data, Charset encoding, boolean append)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20boolean))

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, sb.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8, true);
```